# Running nUnit from code generated by msBuild out of Jenkins

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, jenkins, nunit

My company is moving to continuous integration using Jenkins.
We keep our code in Subversion.
We code in C# (well I do, the others use php).

I've hit a snag, I can't get nUnit to work when I compile the project .

My project is a very simple one with just a single class and a few nUnit tests.
Works fine in Visual Studio.  It builds and I can run the NUnit console to test the code.

I can use Jenkins to extract the project from Subversion
I can then build the code with msBuild.
However, when I try to run NUnit from the the NUnit console I get told that nunit.framework.dll is missing.

nunit.framework.dll is in C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.10\bin\net-2.0\framework

I think it is looking for the nunit.framework.dll that is referenced by the project.  Which is required to add NUnit tests to the project.

I note that when building from Visual Studio nunit.framework.dll is copied to the bin folder.
I note that no contents of bin are stored in Subversion.
I had to put a copy of nunit.framework.dll into 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client
so that msBuild could find it.

How do I get nunit.framework.dll into the output bin folder when using Jenkins and msBuild?

I've looked through a number of posts but non address this point.

Any thoughts would be welcome.
Thanks, 
Richard

Answer (score 2):

In your Test project where you reference the Nunit.Framework.dll, right click on that and select properties ( or press Alt + Enter ) and make `Copy Local` to be `True`

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That's a standard setting so I already have that set.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion does not store output files ( i.e. dlls) by default.  I rebuilt the project and added nunit.framework.dll to subversion.  That way it gets popped out by Jenkins and can subsequently be referenced.

Comment: That is untrue about SVN, it will store whatever you tell it to.  If .dlls are in your svn ignore property, then yes, they will be ignored